# AVSpeechSynthesisVoice not Loading Properly

Tags: ios, speech

I wanted to play with the text to speech on iOS, but I've instantly hit a roadblock. The voice doesn't want to change to a different language or accent. Just for reference, I'm running iOS 9 beta 3, maybe its just a bug, but heres my code:

```
    let utter = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "hello and good morning")
    let voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-au")
    utter.voice = voice

    if voice == nil {
        print("bad voice")
    }

    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    synth.speakUtterance(utter)
```

It does give me this error in console:

```
AXAlternativeVoices was unable to retrieve custom voice assets. This could possibly be caused by someone requesting voices they are not entitled to. Error: Error Domain=ASError Code=15 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ASError error 15 - Unable to copy asset information)" UserInfo=0x13e662970 {NSDescription=Unable to copy asset information}
```

Has anyone else had this issue, I can't find anything online. Thanks.

Comment: @matt This is running on the actual device and it does have the Australian voice.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `"en-au"`, try saying `"en-AU"`.

Comment: Still doesn't work, uses the default voice and prints out bad voice on the console.

Comment: But did the "unable to retrieve custom voice assets" message go away? That is the question I was trying to answer!

Comment: Unfortunately not. I looked on the developer forums, and it seems like a few other people have the same issue, I think its a beta problem, but I could still be wrong.

Comment: Sounds like it, sorry about that. Please be sure to file a bug report with Apple!

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing this same issue in Xcode 7.0 Beta 3 (7A152u) when trying to run in the simulator or in a playground

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed in beta 4. Tried multiple voices and everything seems to be back to normal.